# java.net.BindException when trying to run Jboss on remote system connecting it using RDC

Tags: jboss5.x

I am trying to run JBoss(5.1) on remote system connecting it using RDC. Which ever port I try, it's says already in use and throwing **java.net.BindException Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind**

I have tried to change the port using jboss service binding configuration located at below path:

**jboss\server\Server_Instance\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF\bindings-jboss-beans.xml**

I have tried various options like **ports-01**, **ports-02** ,**ports-03** and then customizing the default port configurations as well with No luck.

I am just wondering how it is possible that it's not allowing any port whichever I try. One thing I would like to let you know here is that the remote system has 3 different logins and all of the users are using the system.

Appreciated if you can provide me any assistance please.

Comment: Does it fail on a specific port? What OS are you using? Have you tried binding to the IP of the machine?

Comment: Thanks for reply.It fails on all the ports whichever I tried. It's default port is 8083. I tried to add 100,200,300 to all the default ports using ports-01,ports-02,ports-03 configuration and also I tried to configure to get in different range like ports above 4000. It never works. I am using window 7 and the remote machine is windows server 2008. I am not sure how can I bind to the IP of the machine. Could you please let me know then I can try.

Comment: You can pass the -b ${IPofMachine} to bind to an IP. This will also make it externally accessible. You can do 0.0.0.0 which will bind to all available IP's.

Comment: Thanks @Welsh. Binding to IP worked perfectly fine. But I am not able to do connect to it from my web application using java.naming.provider.url. I have tried with both the option, IP of machine and 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Your Welcome, I added it as an answer. Are you trying to connect it to it while Remote Connected or from your local?

Comment: I tried to connect it while remote connected. By the way, I have the same jboss setup on my local system as well and I am starting the Jboss locally with same option and trying to connect it from other system which is in LAN. I can ping my system from other local system. But the web application running on other system is not able to connect to my local jboss.

Comment: Check firewall on Windows Server.

Comment: Yes @Welsh , the firewall was the issue. It's all set. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `-b ${IPofMachine}` to bind to an IP. This will also make it externally accessible. You can do 0.0.0.0 which will bind to all available IP's